# dynamically call the variable using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

I have this

```
var cartid = $(this).attr("data-cartid");

var cartid = 3;

        $.ajax({
          url:"/cart/update-quantity",
          method:'POST',
          data:{ cartid:cartid },
          dataType:'json',
          success:function(data)
          {

$('tr').filter('[data-cartid="'+cartid+'"]').find('.item_subtotal').text(data.3);
```

at the back it is being constructed and return as such

```
$ajaxdata[$cart->id] = $item_subtotal;
return json_encode($ajaxdata);
```

console.log output as 3: 480

If I call data.3, it is manually assign 3
now I want to auto map the cartid returned to here
how can I dynamically call data.3

is there anything like eval that can let me call it dynamically as data.3?

Comment: Use bracket notation.... `data[3]` so `data[cartid]`

Comment: wow, tried, this works!   how about if I return to console.log as cart_3: 480?   I tried this and it can't work   $('tr').filter('[data-cartid="'+cartid+'"]').find('.item_subtotal').text(data.cart_[cartid]);